# Error Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' in Android Studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I install Android Studio 3.1.2 and update SDK Platforms, SDK Tools, and download Gradle 4.4 and enable offline work in settimgs.

[image]

I can sync Gradle with Android Studio 3.1.2. also I use this code:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.site.apptest1"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
}
```

But I can not build project. Get This Error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)...
```

Comment: Have you checked your drawable folder for PNG and JPG, Is that okay with name and quality?

Comment: I not use image in my project. my project is empty.